# Using Emits in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I am going to upgrade vue 2 project to vue 3. There are two emits in my vue 2 project. I want to change it as vue 3. I found a way to use emits in vue 3 by using typescript. Here is the script part of code in my upgraded project.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-facing-decorator';
import { DataTableActionTypes } from '@/shared/enums/dataTableActionTypes.enum';
import Modal from '@/shared/components/modal/Modal.vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent ({
    name : 'AddressListActionButtons',
    components: {
        Modal
    },
    props: {
        item : {
            type : undefined,  //since type as any in vue 2 project
        },
        
    },
    showDeleteAddressConfirmation = false,

    methods : {
        onDeleteAddressClick() {
            this.showDeleteAddressConfirmation = true;
            this.onAction(this.item, DataTableActionTypes.ActionButtonSelect);
        },

        onCloseDelete() {
            this.showDeleteAddressConfirmation = false;
            this.onAction(this.item, DataTableActionTypes.ResetActionButtton);
        },
        deleteAddress() {
            this.showDeleteAddressConfirmation = false;
            this.onDeleteAddress(this.item, DataTableActionTypes.Delete)
        }
    },
    

    emits : ['customEvent'],
        setup(props, { emit }) {
            const onAction = (data: any, type: DataTableActionTypes)=>{
            
            }
        },
        
    emits : ['customEvent'],
        setup(props, { emit }) {
            const onDeleteAddress = (id: number, type: DataTableActionTypes)=>{
            
            }
        },    


})
</script>
```

Since there are two emits, there is an error message called **An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.ts(1117)**. Actually this error occurs since I use two emits keywords.
Is there is an solution to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the composition api like this:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineEmits } from "vue";
const emit = defineEmits(["emit1", "emit2"]);

const sendEmit1 = () => {
  emit("emit1");
};
const sendEmit2 = () => {
  emit("emit2");
};
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="sendEmit1">emit 1</button>
  <button @click="sendEmit2">emit 2</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>
```

Working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-silence-70qf73)

Comment: Actually I am using typescript. Because of that, I cannot use **<script setup>**. That's why I use **defineComponent**.   [How to use Vue 3 with TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-vue-3-typescript/)

Comment: @KanchanaKariyawasam you can use it with typescript for sure as you can see in the docs: [https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events)